# Filter does not work when adding 1 in calculating ratio in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a slicer with two values: `Office 1` and `Office 2`

This calculation works fine and gives me correct filtered divisions under `Office 1`

```
   Retention Ratio =  DIVIDE(([RenewalRewritePremium] - [PY Premium]) , [PY Premium])
```

[image]

But as soon as I add `1` before or after `DIVIDE` function it bring all divisions, no matter what Office selected in a slicer:

```
Retention Ratio =  1 + (DIVIDE(([RenewalRewritePremium] - [PY Premium]) , [PY Premium]))
```

[image]

Those divisions with 100% should not be displayed, because they do not belong to `Office 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [PY Premium] should return no value for "Earthquake", "Terrorism", and "Wind". In that case, `DIVIDE` returns `BLANK` because the denominator is `BLANK`.

Then, the measure evaluates `1 + BLANK`. `BLANK` will be converted to `0` when it is added by a number. Therefore it actually calculates `1 + 0` and returns `1`.

To fix this, you can use a variable to keep the result of [PY Premium], and calculate the ratio only when [PY Premium] is not BLANK.

```
Retention Ratio =
VAR PYPremium = [PY Premium]
RETURN IF(
    NOT ISBLANK( PYPremium ),
    1 + DIVIDE( [RenewalRewritePremium] - PYPremium, PYPremium )
)
```

Having said that, above calculation actually looks to return the same result as this. And this will not cause the issue of returning 100% for irrelevant Division.

```
Retention Ratio = DIVIDE( [RenewalRewritePremium], [PY Premium] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant reproduce your error. This works as it should be:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So the error is not in the slicer or the calculation.
Your calculation is a Column not a measure, right?
The error seems to be somewhere else. My guess would be your `Office 1` value is not linked to your values (earthquake, terrorism, wind).

Comment: Thank you for your time. If you want, I can send you a dashboard that gives an error